# Network byte order conversion with "char"

Tags: c++, network-programming

I've always been taught that if an integer is larger than a char, you must solve the byte ordering problem. Usually, I'll just wrap it in the hton[l|s] and convert it back with ntoh[l|s]. But I'm confused why this doesn't apply to single byte characters.

I'm sick of wondering why this is, and would love for a seasoned networks programmer to help me shed some light on why byte orderings only apply for multibyte integers.

Ref: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/htonsman.html

Comment: Appreciate the answers, had one of those "do'h" moments!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you are looking for is [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

A big-endian architecture stores the bytes of a multibyte data type like so:

[image: big-endian]

while a little-endian architecture stores them in reverse:

[image: little-endian]

When data is transferred from one machine to another, the bytes of a single data type must be reordered to correspond with the endianness of the destination machine.

But when a data type only consists of one byte, *there is nothing to reorder*.

Comment: +1, but you might want to reconsider stealing the bandwidth of another site.

Comment: @Bill, Wikipedia's policy on hotlinking is at http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Reusing_content_outside_Wikimedia#Hotlinking -- but wikimedia.org is blocked here, so I can't read it myself. Would you mind paraphrasing it? Thanks!

Comment: I learned something new today, thanks!  Hotlinking paraphrased: "Go to it, but the images might change.  Caveat scriptor."  Bummer about the blocking.

Comment: @MichaelMyers : `But when a data type only consists of one byte, there is nothing to reorder.`Even if I do computations on it like bitwise and or additions *(signed char)*? This is for converting Unicode code points contained in integers to ᴜᴛꜰ-8.

Answer (score 4):

Your networking stack will handle the bits inside the bytes correctly, you must only concern yourself with getting the bytes in the right order.

Answer (score 4):

Exactly how many ways can you order the bytes in a single char?

Comment: +1 for snark. To spell it out: by definition in C and C++ a char is the smallest addressable unit of storage.

Comment: -1 for snark.  You know the answer to a question the OP didn't.  Good for you.  Don't be a jerk about it.

Comment: Lighten up - the OP obviously knows about byte ordering and hton etc - why you don't need this for a byte is just one of those d'oh moments.

Comment: @MartinBeckett : Even if I do computations on it like bitwise and or additions *(signed char)*? This is for converting Unicode code points contained in integers to ᴜᴛꜰ-8.

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider what each function does. From that, you need to apply that knowledge to the size of the type you intend to modify. Consider the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main () {
    uint16_t i = 42;
    uint8_t c = 42; // a char
    printf ("(uint16_t ) %08X (%d)\n", i, i);
    printf ("(   htons ) %08X (%d)\n", htons(i), htons(i));
    printf ("( uint8_t ) %08X (%c)\n", c, c);
    printf ("(   htons ) %08X (%c)\n", htons(c), htons(c));
    return 0;
}

(uint16_t ) 0000002A (42)
(   htons ) 00002A00 (10752)
( uint8_t ) 0000002A (*)
(   htons ) 00002A00 ()
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't read individual bits off the wire, just bytes. Regardless of the endianness, a single byte is the same backwards and forwards just like the word "I" is the same backwards and forwards.

Comment: Many ethernet systems do encode individual bits - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MLT-3, though the faster ones are nibbles.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the other ways folks have put it: Endianness is about the order of bytes in an integer, not about the order of bits in a byte. The order of bits in a byte is the same even across big-endian and little-endian machines. The only difference is the order in which the bytes themselves are used to store an integer (or short or what-have-you). And so because there's only one byte in a char, there's no difference in how that value is stored, either in a big-endian or little-endian architecture.

Comment: Even if I do computations on it like bitwise and or additions *(signed char)*? This is for converting Unicode code points contained in integers to ᴜᴛꜰ-8.

Answer (score 0):

ezpz code is incorrect..

```
uint16_t i = 65534;
printf ("(uint16_t ) %08X (%d)\n", i, i);

Returns...
(uint16_t ) 0000FFFE (-2)
```

You should use a unsigned int instead so it's not interpreted as a signed int

```
uint16_t i = 65534;
printf ("(uint16_t ) %08X (%u)\n", i, i);

Returns...
(uint16_t ) 0000FFFE (65534)
```